# Getting the Query Builder object behind fetching a relation in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

We have modeled self-referencing relations in our User model using `belongsToMany()`. Users can be agent or seller for each other - so we definer `seller()` and `agents()`

Now we are using https://github.com/Nayjest/Grids which needs a query to the grid.

In the grid we want for example to display a seller's agents.

Currently we are using a hand-crafted query for that - but we would like to pull the logic from the model.

So what we need is the query (as query builder object) which is executed when fetching

```
$seller = Auth::user(); // or any other instance of User
$seller->agents
```

We tried

```
$query = $seller->newQuery()->where('laravel_reserved_1.id', '=', $seller->id);
return $user->agents()->getRelationQuery($query, $query);
```

without luck.

*EDIT*

Trying $seller->agents()->getQuery() we get

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in order clause is ambiguous
 (SQL: select * from `users` inner join `user_connections` on 
`users`.`id` = `user_connections`.`user_id` 
where `user_connections`.`related_user_id` = 2 and        
`user_connections`.`type` = agent order by `id` asc 
limit 15 offset 0)
```

Comment: What is the variable `$seller`?

Comment: @TheFallen A User instance

Comment: Isn't it just `$user->agents()->getQuery()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it is just

```
$user->agents()->getQuery()
```

We had a column "id" in the grid which led to the ambiguous query later in the process.